# ¿Como hacer una barra de progreso con ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp

estoy haciendo un fileupload con barra de progreso que muestre el porcentaje de subida pero ala hora de subir el archivo no muestra el porcentaje real de subida alguien puede ayudarme

el codigo que utilizo es el siguiente

con este subo el archivo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAgregaArchivo").click(function (event) {
              //  var files = $("#FileUpload2")[0].files;
                var files = $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").get(0).files;
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                    }

                    var progressbarLabel = $('#progressBar-label');
                    var progressbarDiv = $('#progressbar');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '../FileUploader.ashx',
                        method: 'post',
                        data: formData,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,                      
                        async: false,

                        success: function () {
                            progressbarLabel.text('completo');                           
                            progressbarDiv.fadeOut(2500);
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert(err.statusText);
                        }
                    });

                    progressbarLabel.text('Subiendo....');                    
                    progressbarDiv.progressbar({
                        value: false
                    }).fadeIn(500);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

con este se anima la barra de progreso

```
  $(document).ready(function ($) {

        var bar = $('.progress-bar');
        var percent = $('.percent');
        var status = $('#status');

        $('#form1').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function () {
                status.empty();
                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            complete: function (xhr) {
                status.html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        });
</script>
```

alguien sabe una manera de hacer todo en un solo script?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta de esta manera, a mi me funciona.

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <input class="form-control"  type="file" id="fileArchivos" multiple="multiple"> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Guardar()" type="button">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-md-3'>
                    <div class='col-md-10'>
                        <div class='progress'>
                            <div id='progressBar1' class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='0' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 0%'>0%</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <label id='nombreArchivoCalendario1'> file.name</label>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4'>
                    <input class='form-control' name='comentarioArchivoCalendario1' id='comentarioArchivoCalendario1' type='text' onkeyup='mayusculas(this)' maxlength='450'>
                </div>
            </div>
```

para la sección de javascript solo con esta función debería de bastar

```
function Guardar(){ 
if ($("#fileArchivos")[0].files.length > 0) {

var inputFile = $("#fileArchivos")[0].files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileArchivos', inputFile);

return ajaxReq = $.ajax({
    url: 'filesUpload',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
            var perc = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            $("#nombreArchivoCalendario1").text(inputFile.name);
            $("#progressBar1").text(perc + '%');
            $("#progressBar1").css('width', perc + '%');
        };
        return xhr;
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        $("#progressBar1").text('0%');
        $("#progressBar1").css('width', '0%');
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {        
        $("#progressBar1").addClass("progress-bar-success");
        $("#progressBar1").text('100% - Carga realizada');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) { 
        $("#progressBar1").text('100% - Error al cargar el archivo');
        $("#progressBar1").removeClass("progress-bar-success");
        $("#progressBar1").addClass("progress-bar-danger");
    }
});
}
```

}